# Click event is not firing for button in Lightbox2 caption

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox2

I've added a button to Lightbox2 caption:

```
<a href="link-to-img" data-lightbox="gallery" data-title="
  <div class='popup-button-container'>
    <button class='order-button'>Order now</button>
  </div>"><img src="img.jpg">
</a>
```

The button is vsible but when I try to make onclick function, it doesn't work:

```
$(document).on("click", ".order-button", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('Button clicked');
    $('#popup1').bPopup({
        speed: 850,
        transition: 'slideDown', 
        modalColor: '#000000',
        opacity: 0.5
    });
    return false;
});
```

The same code works for any element with class `order-button` outside of lightbox content.

Comment: Is your content is opening in Lightbox iframe? I think yes. That's why js is not working

Comment: Your html contains errors. Did you also debug your code?

Comment: @SeeTheC No. There is no iframe in dev tools.

Comment: @JeroenHeier Can you tell where are errors please?

Comment: Close data-title quote and remove "> between div and img tags

Comment: can you provide sample code for calling lightbox

Comment: @JeroenHeier Quote is closed. Div is inside data-title attribute. `>` is a closing of `a` tag.

Comment: @SeeTheC `lightbox.option({
      'resizeDuration': 200,
      'wrapAround': true,
   'showImageNumberLabel': false
    });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="link-to-img" data-lightbox="gallery" data-title="
  <div class='popup-button-container'>
    <button class='order-button'>Order now</button>
  </div>"><img src="img.jpg">
</a>
```

You are writing below code is data-title.

```
<div class='popup-button-container'>
        <button class='order-button'>Order now</button>
      </div>
```

Which is being rendered after

> $(document).on.

So you should bind the event when lightbox has been rendered i.e title is being rendered

Comment: Thank :D Changed `$(document).on("click", ".order-button", function(e){` to `$(".lightbox").on("click", '.order-button', function(e){` and now it works!